JedisConnectionException: Unexpected end of stream (when Redis timeout already set to 0)
I've seen a few other questions on SO for this exception, but the answers are generally "set the timeout on the server side to 0" which the Redis instances I've been using already have. There's also the answer to set the idle connections to 0 but then a new connection is created every time which defeats the purpose of a connection pool right? Can someone confirm that a timeout of 0 means no timeout? I'm wondering if the application is expected to handle these connection related issues with retries. This exception occurs infrequently in an application that receives a lot of traffic. Stack trace and client side connection pool config below
Jedis default config
testWhileIdle=true
minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=60000L
timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=30000L
numTestsPerEvictionRun=-1

Manually set config
maxConnections=20
minIdle=2
maxIdle=4

Stack trace
stacktrace:redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException:Unexpected end of stream.In\tat
redis.clients.jedis.util.RedisInputStream.ensureFill(RedisInputStream.java:202)\n\tatredis.clients.jedis.util.RedisInputStream.readByte(RedisInputStream.ja
redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:158)\n\tatredis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:223)\n\tat
redis. clients. jedis. Connection. readProtocolWithCheckingBroken(Connection. java:352)\n\tat redis. clients. jedis, Connection. getStatusCodeReply (Connection. Java:2
redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.ping(BinaryJedis.java:381)\n\tatredis.clients.jedis.JedisFactory.validate04ject(JedisFactory.java:214)\n\tat
org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.evict(GenericObjectPool.java:810)\n\tat
org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.BaseGeneric0bjectPoolsEvictor.run(BaseGenericObjectPool.java:1160)\n\tat
org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.EvictionTimerSWeakRunner.run(EvictionTimer.java:213)\n\tatjava.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Execu
java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)\n\tat
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoo1Executor.java:305)\n\tat
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)\n\tat
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutorSworker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)\n\tatjava.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)\n

